# Can't start mongod , configured storage engine is 'mmapv1'

Tags: 16.04, mongodb

I try to run mongo v2.6.10 on Ubuntu 16.04 lts:

```
mongod
```

And get the result:

```
mongod --help for help and startup options
2017-09-16T12:15:19.660+0430 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=15959 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=mahdi-MS-7808
2017-09-16T12:15:19.660+0430 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.10
2017-09-16T12:15:19.660+0430 [initandlisten] git version: nogitversion
2017-09-16T12:15:19.660+0430 [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
2017-09-16T12:15:19.660+0430 [initandlisten] build info: Linux lgw01-12 3.19.0-25-generic #26~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 24 21:16:20 UTC 2015 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_58
2017-09-16T12:15:19.660+0430 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2017-09-16T12:15:19.660+0430 [initandlisten] options: {}
2017-09-16T12:15:19.660+0430 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 28574 Cannot start server. Detected data files in /data/db created by storage engine 'wiredTiger'. The configured storage engine is 'mmapv1'., terminating
2017-09-16T12:15:19.660+0430 [initandlisten] dbexit: 
2017-09-16T12:15:19.660+0430 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2017-09-16T12:15:19.660+0430 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2017-09-16T12:15:19.660+0430 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2017-09-16T12:15:19.660+0430 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2017-09-16T12:15:19.660+0430 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
2017-09-16T12:15:19.660+0430 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
2017-09-16T12:15:19.660+0430 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
2017-09-16T12:15:19.660+0430 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
2017-09-16T12:15:19.660+0430 [initandlisten] dbexit: really exiting now
```

error :

> exception in initAndListen: 28574 Cannot start server. Detected data
>   files in /data/db created by storage engine 'wiredTiger'. The
>   configured storage engine is 'mmapv1'., terminating

after update mongodb show error .

Comment: Is this a fresh install?

Comment: Not installed fresh.
But I just updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> exception in initAndListen: 28574 Cannot start server. Detected data files in /data/db created by storage engine 'wiredTiger'. The configured storage engine is 'mmapv1'., terminating

The WiredTiger storage engine is only supported in MongoDB 3.0 or newer, so you cannot use these data files with MongoDB 2.6. I would also note that MongoDB 2.6 [reached end of life](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-2-6-end-of-life) in October, 2016 and is no longer supported.

If you are unsure what version of MongoDB your data files were created with, I would suggest installing the latest version of MongoDB (currently the 3.4 release series). See: [Install MongoDB Community Edition on Ubuntu](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/).

Comment: I am using MongoDB version 4.0.4 and I get the same error. I am on mac though. Installed MongoDB with homebrew. The directory in the error msg is different ('/dbdata'), even though I have '/data/db' directory available. Can you help me out here?

Comment: @Skywalker Please post a new question on [DBA StackExchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/mongodb) with details of how you installed MongoDB (Homebrew or tarball download), how you are starting MongoDB, and the messages you are getting on start up. The directory `/dbdata` isn't a standard location, so you must be starting `mongod` using a config file command line parameter (or a service definition that includes this). It would also be helpful to know the provenance of your data directory (for example, were files copied from a previous version of MongoDB or is this a new install).